# Umap map - How to unify the cities (like Beijing and Shanghai) into "identical" country (China) after import umap files?

Tags: dictionary

I have 2 city umap files (Shanghai and Beijing) with polygon marked on each.  I need to load them together under "identical" China but now they're show "separately" like below :

[image: Image after load both files in Umap]

Things I try:

- There's a chinese layer name in Shanghai file, I adjust them in English but still not work
- One of alternative was to move the polygon manually from "A" China to "B" China, but I have a lot of polygon, and the "moving" distance is a bit long, it's quite stupid to do that

Things I expect:

- both cities show in identical China in map